Error 502 en la implementación de Railway con Docker y Nginx
Estoy implementando Laravel en Railway usando nginx y docker. La implementación es casi exitosa, lo que significa que no arroja ningún error, pero cuando navego a la URL, obtengo un error 502 en los registros HTTP de Railway. ¿Alguna idea de qué podría estar sucediendo?
vhost.conf:
Esta configuracion esta preparada para trabajar con laravel, y vite.
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /build/ {
        proxy_pass http://node:5173/build/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /__vite_ping {
        proxy_pass http://node:5173/__vite_ping;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /@vite {
        proxy_pass http://node:5173;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

docker-compose.yml:
Aca configuro mi docker-compose.yml para que levante los imagenes necesarias para mi aplicacion, estas son: base de datos, app, selenium, servidor web y node.
services:
  app:
    container_name: laravel-app
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=5432"
      - "DB_HOST=database"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  web:
    container_name: laravel-web
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - app

  database:
    container_name: laravel-database
    image: postgres:11.2
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/pgsql
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_DB=mydb"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=myuser"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=expensecontrolpassword"
    ports:
        - "54321:5432"

  selenium:
    container_name: laravel-selenium
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome

  adminer:
    container_name: laravel-adminer
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8080

  node:
    image: node:18.19.1
    container_name: laravel_node
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    entrypoint: ["/var/www/entrypoint.sh"]
    ports:  
      -  "5173:5173"

volumes:
  dbdata: {}

app.dockerfile:
Imagen con la version de php a usar
FROM php:8.3-fpm
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

web.dockerfile:
Imagen de nginx con la version que uso
FROM nginx:1.19.10

ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Revisé los logs y no encuentro ningún tipo de información para saber qué está pasando.

tengo el mismo problema , lograste solucionarlo (?)
